# Resolve url from external DNS on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In my K8s cluster i've a pod who tried to resolved a url with DNS outwards of kubernetes. I dont have a choice i've to use this external DNS :( .

I overwrite **/etc/resolv.conf** in my pod but that doesn't change anything .

Do you have an idea or tutorial about how i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

> I overwrite /etc/resolv.conf in my pod but that doesn't change anything .

If for no other reason because that file is volume-mounted into your container, and very, very likely read on container start by the libraries it affects. IOW, you have modified it too late.

> Do you have an idea or tutorial about how i can do it ?

[PodSpec: dnsConfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#poddnsconfig-v1-core) and/or its `dnsPolicy` friend

Comment: I tried the **dnsPolicy** without success :(  .  from my pod if i try to ping the dns **10.96.0.10**  i cant   but if i try to ping  **10.109.0.10** given by kubernetes it success !

Comment: Be forewarned that ping is TCP, but DNS is a UDP protocol. Can you use `dig` or `nslookup` or whatever to attempt an actual DNS query? Also, what are the Service CIDR and Pod CIDRs for your SDN?

Comment: "from my pod ... i cant but if i try ... it success" can you clarify that statement? What does "but if I try" mean?

Comment: which dnsPolicy are you using? the default is clusterfirst
Also if you are trying to reach an IP that overlaps with your cluster CIDR (GKE default is 10.0.0.0/8), you need to modify the [masquerade value](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)